# RoR - model vs. database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

In `RoR`, when I run the following command for example:

`> rails generate model xyz`

And, if I go to for example `12345_create_xyzs.rb`, I will find something similar to this:

```
def self.up
    create_table :xyzs do |t|
```

So, when I made a `model`, am I actually making a *table*?

But, where is the **database**?!

Answer (score 3):

When you use `rails generate model zyz`, you are telling Rails to generate several files for you. The file `12345_create_xyzs.rb` is what is called a migration - it contains the instructions to populate a database with the table structure associated with your model.

You do, however, need to make sure that the DB exists (so, for example in MySql `CREATE DATABASE MyDB`), and your `database.yml` file has the correct connection information to that database.

If this is true, when you run `rake db:migrate`, the rake task will take care of migrating your model structure to the database.

Answer (score 2):

When you `rails generate model xyz`, you will be specifying the fields (and other things like the database indexes you want) that the table xyz will have in the database. The table is representing the model *class* in the database.

To create that table in the database, you would migrate the model definition file (`12345_create_xyzs.rb`) using `rake db:migrate`.

The model is represented in Rails (i.e. ActiveRecord) code as a class, in a file called `app/models/xyz.rb`:

```
class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

You create the `app/models/xyz.rb` file in addition to the migration file created above by `rails generate model`. In this class is where you put things like specifying relationships between models, adding constraints and other code you need.

Comment: I think `def Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base` has to be `class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base`. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the command `rake db:migrate` in order to migrate the database. The command `rake db:create` creates the database...

More information available [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

In addition, the database must be configured into the file situated here :

```
<your_project>/config/database.yml
```

More information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database).
More generally, I think you really should read the "[getting started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)".